# cpanel mail forwarding not working

Tags: cpanel

Forwarding is (I believe) set up correctly.Messages sent to domain addresses this morning that should have been forwarded have not been received by the target email account

result of /var/log/exim_mainlog is as follows
2015-04-02 02:31:22 1YdY8G-0004Ol-Ve == to@emailid (from@emailid)  R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2015-04-02 02:31:22 1YdY8G-0004Ol-Ve ** to@emailid : retry timeout exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Please try to setup your mail forward to different mail account. I think your mail server IP is block on remote server and due to that you are getting timeout in mail logs.